# Guest machine (Windows XP) can't ping host (Windows 7) and Guest machine (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I want to create small virtual network. I am using VMWare Workstation 10.  First I installed Guest Ubuntu machine and I could ping from host to that Guest Machine. But when I installed Windows XP as a new Guest machine, new Windows XP Guest could not ping any IP address (host on Windows 7 and Guest on Ubuntu 12.04). To get fresh gateway I created new Virtual Gateway for Guest XP

Here is screenshot of VMWare Virtual Network Editor:

[image: Configuration of Virtual adapters in VMWorkspace]

And here is output when I ping gateway of Host (Windows 7)

[image: Pinging Host machine]

Can someone tells me why I can't ping from Guest Windows XP machine and how to fix it ? 
Regards...

Answer (score 1):

It's probably that Windows, by default, blocks ping requests. You will have to open up a hole in your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using workstation pro. In the normal.worstation is no option to run the systems at the same time, so probably by switching you suspend the guest - you have to open two worstations.